# Where to stop a taylor expansion of a function of more than one variable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

I tried to taylor expand a function of three variables $f(x,y,z)$ around $y=0,z=0$ but I don't find a way to decide where to stop the expansion.

Usually when one expands a function of one variable $g(x)$ around $x=0$

$
g(0)+\partial_x g(0) \cdot x + \frac 1 2 \partial^2_x g(0) \cdot x^2 + \mathcal O (x^3)
$

one can immediately say that contributions of (say) $x^3$ or higher can be neglected if $x^3$ is already smaller than the desired precision.

But in the case of three variables I get an expansion like

$
f(x,0,0) + \partial_yf(x,0,0)\cdot y + \partial_zf(x,0,0)\cdot z+\frac 1 2 \big(\partial_y^2f(x,0,0)\cdot y^2  + 2\partial_y\partial_z f(x,0,0)\cdot yz + \partial^2_z f(x,0,0)\cdot z^2\big) + ...
$

but I don't have any clue where to stop. I think the reason is that there are still functions on $x$ to which I can't say anything about their order in opposite to the one dimensional case where just constants appear.

So for example when I say that both $y$ and $z$ are very small but $z$ is way smaller than $y$ and I keep a term like $\partial^2_z f(x,0,0)\cdot z^2$ then there is no reason to neglect the term (say) $\partial_y^7\partial_zf(x,0,0)\cdot y^7z$ since the latter can be bigger than the former for some $x$.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor expansion of degree $k$ will involve *all* terms $x^ay^bz^c$ with $0\le a+b+c\le k$, and then the error will be $O\big((x^2+y^2+z^2)^{(k+1)/2}\big)$. You need to work simultaneously with all three variables.

Comment: thanks for your answer. hm, but then it is pointless for my situation. because in my case $y$ and $z$ are very small (almost 0) and $x$ shall be general. so is there no way to handle that?

Comment: Well, you can handle it by fixing $x=x_0$ for any value of $x_0$ and looking near the point $(x_0,0,0)$. What I said then applies to the polynomial whose terms are of the form $(x-x_0)^ay^bz^c$ ...

Comment: Hm, no this is no option for me. The dependence on $x$ is so important that I can not expand it (I would at least need terms with $x^6$)... but what I did is the following: I just ignored the x dependency and pretended that I have a funcion just of $y$ and $z$. I then just guessed the important orders and the result agrees perfectly with the exact version of the function. I think there must be a way to understand that mathematically...

Comment: Sure. You can do that. Mathematically, we think of a family of functions $f_x(y,z)$, where we view $x$ as a parameter.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I now have a problem with the error term $\mathcal O\big((y^2+z^2)^{(k+1)/2}\big)$, because my variables have physical units. $y$ is an angle in radiant and $z$ is a length in meter, so adding up $y^2+z^2$ makes no sense. I already saw at some stage before that it is problematic to expand a function in variables with units... but what should I do? I tried to expand in unitless variables but it is a bit artificial then... of course at the end the forced parameter (which I introduced to make a variable unitless) cancels out...

Comment: It seems to me that problem occurs term by term. The units are not going to match up as you go from the zeroth term to the first to the second ...

Comment: no there is no problem since a derivative say $\partial^n_y f$ multiplied with $y^n$ cancels out the unit.

Comment: Oh, well, the error term can be thought of as a polynomial of degree $k+1$, whose coefficients, although not constant, will likewise make each term unitless.

Comment: no, there is still the problem with ADDING up quantities with different units. that does not make sense...

Comment: You are then contradicting yourself. I'm telling you that whatever rationale you have for the terms of degrees $0$, $1$, $\dots$, $k$, applies as well to the remainder term(s).